# error validating data: [ValidationError(CronJob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec): unknown field "container" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec,

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-cronjob

This is my yaml file that i am trying to use for cronJob creation. I am getting error like unknown field "container" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec,

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: abc-service-cron-job
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          container:
          - name: abc-service-cron-job
            image: docker.repo1.xyz.com/hui-services/abc-application/REPLACE_ME
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Under spec is container**s** not "container"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:  # <-- you have spelling error here, should be "containers"
          ...
```

Comment: Hi Tahnk you. That is resolved. I am getting another error now container "abc-cron-job" in pod "abc-cron-job-1644910560-zw2lc" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled

Comment: `docker.repo1.xyz.com/hui-services/abc-application/REPLACE_ME` - check if the image url is correct -> check the repository is indeed reachable from the **host** -> check if you need to be authenticate first by the registry server -> check if you can pull it successfully from the **host** (eg. docker pull, ctr image pull etc).

Comment: You should create a new question.